# How to keep the header sorting after datagridview update

Tags: winforms, datagridview

In my example, the column 'DEProduct' is sorted desc.

[image]

When I do a datagridview update, everything is restored directly to the default datasource values, and I lose my columnheader sorting.

[image]

I have a lot of columns, so how can I go back to this columnheader sorting, without checking them all before which one was selected, and trigger it manually after?

Comment: Can you clarify (better with code) what *datagridview update* implies? -- If you're sorting the Control and not the data, you could store the state of the DGV's Columns `SortMode` and reapply after... after what? Otherwise, save the Name of the Column that sorts the data and use that Name to `ORDER BY` the incoming data (is it fetched by an SQL command?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention *datasource*, so the only way I can see that you are seeing the described situation is that you are resetting the datasource such that the DataGridview rebinds to a new source.

You can store the current sort state using the [DataGridView.SortedColumn Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortedcolumn?view=net-5.0) and the [DataGridView.SortOrder Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortorder?view=net-5.0). Then do your update.  After the update, restore the stored sort state.

```
  ' since it is asumed that the datasource changes, store only the column name
  Dim sortColName As String = dgv1.SortedColumn?.Name 'dgv1.SortedColumn may be null
  Dim direction As SortOrder = dgv1.SortOrder

  UpdateData() ' replace this with your Update code

  ' restore the sort state if any
  If sortColName IsNot Nothing Then
    Dim columnToSort As DataGridViewColumn = dgv1.Columns(sortColName)
    If columnToSort IsNot Nothing Then
      Dim directionProgrammatic As System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection
      Select Case direction
        Case SortOrder.Ascending
          directionProgrammatic = System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending
        Case SortOrder.Descending
          directionProgrammatic = System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending
      End Select
      dgv1.Sort(columnToSort, directionProgrammatic)
      columnToSort.HeaderCell.SortGlyphDirection = direction
    End If
  End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding answer writen in C# for the same thing as TnTinMn

```
var sortColName = dgv1.SortedColumn;
var sortDirection = dgv1.SortOrder;


UpdateData() ' replace this with your Update code

if (sortColName != null)
{
     dgv1.Sort(sortColName,
          sortDirection == SortOrder.Ascending
              ? ListSortDirection.Ascending
              : ListSortDirection.Descending);
 }
```