# Python .NET Winforms - If SortedColumn returns Null, an error is generated

Tags: python, winforms, datagridview, clr, ironpython

All,

I am working a Winforms Form that has a DataGridView. I have gotten everything working the way I want with the exception of one last ask.

If a user makes changes (or not) to a child form of mine and has a column sorted, the sorting is then removed when the datasource refreshes. I researched this and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65027479/10553930) where if any column was sorted, the developer used programming code to place the sorting back into the datagridview.

This works fine in C# or VB but, when using Python CLR, using this line of code:

```
self.dgvExpanderInfo.SortedColumn.Name
```

I get an error message that states 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Name' because it returns Null since no sorting has taken place.

How do I get past this? Using `if self.dgvExpanderInfo.SortedColumn.Name != None:` generates the same error.

Comment: That post uses `dgv1.SortedColumn?.Name`, meaning the Name property is only read if `SortedColumn` is not null. You have to verify that before reading `Name`

Comment: @Jimi Thank you for the hint. A simple Try...Catch got me past that.